# notation for the regression equation in a nested and repeated measures random effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I'm looking for help with regard to the notation for a regression equation in a repeated measures model with nested data, $\eqref{eq:2}$, and connecting the notation *back* to my model specification, `Model.3`, in [r](/questions/tagged/r).

My starting point is, i.e. I am familiar, the notation used in Wooldridge's *Introductory* (2013). Wooldridge's notation for the general longitudinal model for both Random Effects and Fixed Effects Estimation is can be written as,

$$
y_{it} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{it} + a_{i}+u_{it} \tag{1} \label{eq:1}
$$
where individuals are indexed by $i = 1, 2, …, n$ and time is indexed by $t = 1,2, …, T$. The error term is in two parts; $a_i$ an *unobserved individual specific component*, which captures unobserved, time-constant, factors and $u_{it}$ the *idiosyncratic error*, capturing unobserved factors that change over time.

In [r](/questions/tagged/r) I've been estimating a Random Effects version of this model using the [plm](/questions/tagged/plm) package like this. First some required packages and some data,

```
# install.packages(c("plm", "lme4", "texreg", "mlmRev"), dependencies = TRUE)
data(egsingle, package = "mlmRev")
```

the data-set `egsingle` is a unbalanced panel consisting of 1721 school children, grouped in 60 schools, across five time points. For details see `?mlmRev::egsingle`

Some light data management

```
dta <- egsingle
dta$Female <- with(dta, ifelse(female == 'Female', 1, 0))
```

Also, a snippet of the relevant data

```
dta[118:127,c('schoolid','childid','math','year','size','Female')]
#>     schoolid   childid   math year size Female
#> 118     2040 289970511 -1.830 -1.5  502      1
#> 119     2040 289970511 -1.185 -0.5  502      1
#> 120     2040 289970511  0.852  0.5  502      1
#> 121     2040 289970511  0.573  1.5  502      1
#> 122     2040 289970511  1.736  2.5  502      1
#> 123     2040 292772811 -3.144 -1.5  502      0
#> 124     2040 292772811 -2.097 -0.5  502      0
#> 125     2040 292772811 -0.316  0.5  502      0
#> 126     2040 293550291 -2.097 -1.5  502      0
#> 127     2040 293550291 -1.314 -0.5  502      0
```

Now, here’s how I would specify the *Random Effects Model* in [r](/questions/tagged/r), ignoring the  `schoolid`, based on $\eqref{eq:1}$, using `plm()` and estimating with FGLS,

```
library(plm)
Model.1 <- plm(math~Female+size+year, dta, index = c("childid", "year"), model="random")
# summary(reg.re.plm)
```

However, as mentioned at the top, the data is also nested. That is, `childid` is nested in `schoolid`. To write this regression equation I've simply extended $\eqref{eq:1}$ by adding a school-subscript, $s$,

$$
y_{ist} = \beta_{0}+\beta_{1}x_{ist} + a_{i}+\nu_{s}+u_{ist} \tag{2} \label{eq:2}
$$
now $y$, $x$, and the *idiosyncratic error*, $u$, is extended with a $s$ dimension, and the *combined* error, that in $\eqref{eq:1}$ consist of two parts, is in $\eqref{eq:2}$ extended by a term, $\nu_{s}$. This term then captures the *unobserved group/school specific component*. I am not confident that this specification is correct. I might be confused by the differences in jargon across the literature.

> **Part 1** Is $\eqref{eq:2}$ a correct way to specify a regression equation for repeated measures random effects model with a nested structure? Any authoritative literature that use notation similar to this?

This next part, **Part 2**, is no longer that relevant.

> > <s>I have tried finding a way to estimate what I believe is $\eqref{eq:2}$ using [plm](/questions/tagged/plm), but I haven't succeeded in that. **Part 2** Is it possible to estimate a *repeated measures random effects model with a nested structure* using the [plm](/questions/tagged/plm) package?</s>  Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49329807/1305688) I believe this part is answered by a *yes it is estimate to estimate a _repeated measures random effects model with a nested structure_ using the [plm](/questions/tagged/plm) package, see the the question linked above*

I have estimated, after studding [this great answer by Robert Long](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/10275), a repeated measures model, with `childid` nested in `schoolid`, using the [lme4](/questions/tagged/lme4) package. Like this,

```
dta$year <- as.factor(dta$year) 
require(lme4)
```

As the [lme4](/questions/tagged/lme4) package is relying on a likelihood framework I begin by estimating a model similar to `Model.1` above (for later comparison). Like this,

```
Model.2 <- lmer(math ~ Female + size + year + (1 | childid), dta)
```

Now, relying on [Robert Long's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/10275) I've specified the nested model like this,

```
Model.3 <- lmer(math~Female+size+year+(1| schoolid /childid), dta)
```

Assuming `Model.3` is correct specified.

> **Part 3.a** What authoritative source do you recommend, preferably with notation similar to Wooldridge (2013), that presents and discuss the notation for the regression equations for what I am estimating in `Model.3`?
>
> **Part 3.b** Is $\eqref{eq:2}$ actually what I am estimating in `Model.3`?

Below is the actual estimation results form the three models,

```
# require(texreg)
texreg::screenreg(list(Model.1, Model.2, Model.3), digits = 3)    
#> =============================================================================
#>                                    Model 1       Model 2        Model 3      
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)                          -2.671 ***     -2.669 ***     -2.693 ***
#>                                      (0.085)        (0.086)        (0.152)   
#> Female                               -0.025         -0.025          0.008    
#>                                      (0.046)        (0.047)        (0.042)   
#> size                                 -0.000 ***     -0.000 ***     -0.000    
#>                                      (0.000)        (0.000)        (0.000)   
#> year-1.5                              0.878 ***      0.876 ***      0.866 ***
#>                                      (0.059)        (0.059)        (0.059)   
#> year-0.5                              1.882 ***      1.880 ***      1.870 ***
#>                                      (0.059)        (0.058)        (0.058)   
#> year0.5                               2.575 ***      2.574 ***      2.562 ***
#>                                      (0.059)        (0.059)        (0.059)   
#> year1.5                               3.149 ***      3.147 ***      3.133 ***
#>                                      (0.060)        (0.059)        (0.059)   
#> year2.5                               3.956 ***      3.954 ***      3.939 ***
#>                                      (0.060)        (0.060)        (0.060)   
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> R^2                                   0.735                                  
#> Adj. R^2                              0.735                                  
#> Num. obs.                          7230           7230           7230        
#> AIC                                              16855.629      16590.715    
#> BIC                                              16924.489      16666.461    
#> Log Likelihood                                   -8417.815      -8284.357    
#> Num. groups: childid                              1721                       
#> Var: childid (Intercept)                             0.857                   
#> Var: Residual                                        0.334          0.334    
#> Num. groups: childid:schoolid                                    1721        
#> Num. groups: schoolid                                              60        
#> Var: childid:schoolid (Intercept)                                   0.672    
#> Var: schoolid (Intercept)                                           0.180    
#> =============================================================================
#> *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

[mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model) [repeated-measures](/questions/tagged/repeated-measures) [nested-data](/questions/tagged/nested-data) [r](/questions/tagged/r) [lme4-nlme](/questions/tagged/lme4-nlme) [plm](/questions/tagged/plm)

Wooldridge, Jeffrey M. (2013). Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach. 5th edition. South-Western College, 2013. isbn: 9781285414645. url: https://www.cengage.co.uk/books/9781111531041/

Comment: Yes, your (2) is what you are estimating with your model 3, apart from the fact that you have `Female + size` in your models but this is missing from your formulas (1) and (2).

Comment: @amoeba, thank you for your prompt response. That was surprisingly straightforward. I imaged _x_ being a vector of all the independent variables, i.e. `Female` and `size`. Do you happen to know if (2) can be estimated using `plm` from the `plm` package?

Comment: Don't know about `plm`.

Comment: FWIW for multiple independent variables you'd have to have $\beta_1$ be a vector as well (transposed/oriented so that $\beta_1 x_{ist}$ is a dot product).  AFAICT eq. (2) and `Model 3` are indeed the same. Is that your entire question ...?

Comment: @BenBolker, thank you for your comment! I guess, as most of what I wrote seems to be close to correct, that your comment, along with `amoeba`’s comment, answers almost _the entire question_. I am still looking for a textbook presentation of (2), preferably something that follows the notation style used above - or what source you would recommend? cf. **Part 3.a** above. A source that covers your point about $\beta_1$, more about how what is transposed, what assumptions change, what misspecification test is recommended, and related. Again, I very much appreciate you take the time to comment!

Comment: can't really help you with sources, since pretty much all of the sources I follow (Gelman and Hill *Applied Regression Modeling*, Pinheiro and Bates, Bates et al. *J Stat Software* ...) use the multilevel-style rather than the econometrics-style notation. As for things like misspecification testing -- I think you'd better off asking more focused questions ...

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks a lot. I'll keep working on it and post a more focused question down the road. Again, thank you for your time and consideration.